# Best package for drawing dance charts

Tags: charts

I want to draw dance step chart.
Something similar to

[image: this]
<sub>(source: [community.ca.com](http://community.ca.com/blogs/itil/dance_steps.jpg))</sub>

I was wondering if maybe dedicated package exists or is my only option to use "normal" drawing tools. Maybe something like `Tikz`?

Does anyone have any experience with something like this?. What would you recommend?

Comment: Actually, Tikz seems to be perfect for this, by defining a new node for footprint

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would use TikZ; here's a little initial code that could be highly improved, but the idea is to define one basic shape (for the right foot, the other, for the left one is a simple reflection) and then it seems simple to place the shapes in the desired positions using nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\rifoot{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
  \path[fill=black] (0,0) -- (3,0) -- (2,-5) -- (0,-5) -- cycle;
  \fill (1.5,0) circle (1.5); 
  \fill (1,-5.5) circle (1); 
  \fill[white] (0,-5) rectangle (2,-5.5); 
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand\lefoot{\scalebox{-1}[1]{\rifoot}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% the feet
\node (l1) at (0,0) {\lefoot};
\node (r1) at (2,-2) {\rifoot};
\node (l2) at (0,-5) {\lefoot};
\node (r2) at (2,-7) {\rifoot};
\node[rotate=-80] (l3) at (7,1) {\lefoot};
\node[rotate=-120] (r3) at (5.5,-2) {\rifoot};
\node[rotate=-120]  (r4) at (5.5,-6) {\rifoot};

% the arrows
\draw[ultra thick,->,dashed] (l1.north) to[out=90,in=135] (l3);
\draw[ultra thick,->] ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=0.5cm]r3.east) -- +(0,-2);

% the labels
\node[font=\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries] at ([xshift=-1cm]l2.west) {1.};
\node[font=\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries] at ([xshift=-1cm]l1.west) {2.};
\node[font=\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries] at ([xshift=3.5cm,yshift=2cm]r3.east) {3.};
\node[font=\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries] at ([xshift=3.5cm,yshift=1cm]r4.east) {4.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Paulo Cereda** has kinly provided me with some nicer shapes for the feet and now the overall aspect improves:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\rifoot{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{rifoot}}
\newcommand\lefoot{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{lefoot}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% the feet
\node (l1) at (0,0) {\lefoot};
\node (r1) at (0.7,-0.7) {\rifoot};
\node (l2) at (0,-2) {\lefoot};
\node (r2) at (0.7,-2.7) {\rifoot};
\node[rotate=-60] (l3) at (2.8,-0) {\lefoot};
\node[rotate=-120] (r3) at (2,-0.8) {\rifoot};
\node[rotate=-120]  (r4) at (2,-2.5) {\rifoot};

% the arrows
\draw[ultra thick,->,dashed] (l1.north) to[out=90,in=90] (l3.west);
\draw[ultra thick,->] ([xshift=-10pt,yshift=0pt]r3.east) -- +(0,-1);

% the labels
\node[font=\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries] at ([xshift=-1cm]l2.west) {1.};
\node[font=\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries] at ([xshift=-1cm]l1.west) {2.};
\node[font=\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries] at ([xshift=1.7cm,yshift=0.5cm]r3.east) {3.};
\node[font=\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries] at ([xshift=1.7cm]r4.east) {4.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here are the PNG images:

[image]

[image]